# In which Kitaro manga does he visit Easter Island?

Tags: gegege-no-kitaro

I am the curator of an exhibition on Easter Island in popular culture and I am trying to track down a few missing items. If you can assist we will acknowledge you in the exhibition.

We are aware that Kitaro visits Easter Island in a 1972 television anime. But we understand this story was either based on a manga or later translated into one.

[image: the manga panel showing Moai statue]

In which manga and how can I purchase/acquire a copy?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. Can you please indicate what manga this is about as googling "kitaro manga" gets me [GeGeGe no Kitarō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeGeGe_no_Kitar%C5%8D) which doesn't look right to me

Comment: @Memor-X *GeGeGe no Kitaro* actually sounds right to me, seeing that the first anime adaptation contained [a 1972 Easter Island episode](https://gegegenokitaro.fandom.com/wiki/Series_2_Episode_35).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, "[Easter Island Epitaph](https://gegegenokitaro.fandom.com/wiki/Series_2_Episode_35)" is the 35th episode in series 2 of *GeGeGe no Kitaro* (1971) anime. However, the manga the story was based on is *not* from *GeGeGe no Kitaro*, but from ***World Mysteries* series**, another original manga by Shigeru Mizuki.

The *World Mysteries* series (世界怪奇シリーズ) contains 8 short manga:

1. Yōkai Flower Alraune
2. The Woman of Angkor Wat
3. **Easter Island Epitaph**
4. The Rainbow Kingdom Agartha
5. Neko-Mata's Love
6. Invitation from the South
7. Persian Twilight
8. Amagami Yumuchaac

As for the "Easter Island Epitaph" chapter itself, it has appeared in a few publications:

1. *Big Comic* magazine (1968.06.01)
2. *[Rainbow Country Agartha](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=93976)* (虹の国アガルタ) (1971.03)
3. [*Kaiki Shinin Chou*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=86118) (1985.01)
4. [*He no Youna Jinsei*](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/8718798) (屁のような人生) (2009.12)
5. [*The Complete Shigeru Mizuki Manga Collection*](https://gegegenokitaro.fandom.com/wiki/The_Complete_Shigeru_Mizuki_Manga_Collection) vol. 69 (水木しげる漫画大全集(069) 世界怪奇シリーズ(全)／サラリーマン死神(全) 他) (2013.07)

Unfortunately, the whole publications haven't been licensed in English, so there's no way to acquire it legally. However, for the original Japanese version, *The Complete Shigeru Mizuki Manga Collection* vol. 69 can be purchased on:

1. Amazon Japan: [Printed Comic](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E6%80%AA%E5%A5%87%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%80%94%E5%85%A8%E3%80%95-%E3%82%B5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E6%AD%BB%E7%A5%9E%E3%80%94%E5%85%A8%E3%80%95%E4%BB%96-%E6%B0%B4%E6%9C%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB%E5%A4%A7%E5%85%A8%E9%9B%86-%E6%B0%B4%E6%9C%A8-%E3%81%97%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B/dp/4063775224) / [Kindle Edition](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E6%80%AA%E5%A5%87%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%80%94%E5%85%A8%E3%80%95%EF%BC%8F%E3%82%B5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E6%AD%BB%E7%A5%9E%E3%80%94%E5%85%A8%E3%80%95%E4%BB%96-%E6%B0%B4%E6%9C%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB%E5%A4%A7%E5%85%A8%E9%9B%86-%E6%B0%B4%E6%9C%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B-ebook/dp/B01KZCBJ5M)
2. Yodobashi (Japanese): [Printed Comic](https://www.yodobashi.com/product/100000009001882573/) / [E-book Version](https://www.yodobashi.com/product/100000086600452553/) (need [Doly](http://doly.jp/index.html#dolyDownload) app to read)
3. [Apple Books (Japanese)](https://books.apple.com/jp/book/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E6%80%AA%E5%A5%87%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA-%E5%85%A8-%E3%82%B5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E6%AD%BB%E7%A5%9E-%E5%85%A8-%E4%BB%96-%E6%B0%B4%E6%9C%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB%E5%A4%A7%E5%85%A8%E9%9B%86/id1147527583?ign-mpt=uo%3D4) (digital)
4. [Book Walker (Japanese)](https://bookwalker.jp/de4609986e-13f7-42d5-ae41-97dd24154b55/?adpcnt=7qM_FM2) (digital)
5. or look for the alternatives listed on [Kodansha Comic Plus (Japanese)](http://kc.kodansha.co.jp/product?item=0000045669#online)

---

Sidenote: the reason why *GeGeGe no Kitaro* anime used another manga series was that there was not enough material to be adapted at that time. Out of 45 episodes, 23 episodes were adapted from non-*Kitaro* series.

---

References:

- [TomePage - Listing of *World Mysteries* series publication (Japanese)](http://www.lares.dti.ne.jp/~hisadome/mizuki_2/sekai_kaiki_series.html)
- [AniOta - *GeGeGe no Kitaro* <Series 2>) (Japanese)](https://www49.atwiki.jp/aniwotawiki/pages/12269.html)

Comment: Thanks.That is extremely helpful and explains a few things we did not understand. Crucially, we did not realize that the anime episode was based on a different manga series. Of the publications you mention in which 'Easter island Epitaph' appears do you know if any are available on Amazon/ elsewhere as I'm having no luck. I believe it appears in this collection. Is that true?

Comment: @IanC I have edited the answer to add where you can buy it, perhaps it's better to buy the digital (Kindle/e-book) version for convenience. However, I'm afraid I can't help further on how to navigate the site in Japanese and purchase it...